# Remove files with smallest filename suffixes

Tags: command-line, files, filenames, rm

I have a directory of files with similar names, but with incrementing digits as a suffix.  I want to remove the lower suffixed files and only keep the files with the highest suffix.  Below is an example file listing:

```
1k_02.txt
1k_03.txt
1l_02.txt
1l_03.txt
1l_04.txt
2a_05.txt
2a_06.txt
4c_03.txt
4c_04.txt
```

The above list needs to be reduced to the files below:

```
1k_03.txt
1l_04.txt
2a_06.txt
4c_04.txt
```

I don't even know where to start with this, but if possible I would like a single bash command.

Comment: explain your removing logic, how files with duplicate suffixes should be processed? Why `1k_03.txt` should be kept but `4c_03.txt` should be removed?

Comment: There’s different prefixes for each.

Comment: @user - are you opposed to a zsh-based command that would accomplish the goal? I don’t know one, but suspect there may be. e.g. `zsh -c ‘rm ....’`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest - The suffix is a version number for the file; I want to keep the highest version of each file and remove the remainder, but not all files were incremented uniformly.  Unfortunately the date stamps were all reset so all I have to go by are the file names.

Comment: @JeffSchaller - Anything goes, although I've never used zsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complex *pipeline*:

Files list:

```
$ ls
1l_04.txt 2a_05.txt 4c_03.txt 1k_03.txt 1l_02.txt 4c_04.txt 2a_06.txt 1l_03.txt 1k_02.txt
```

---

```
printf "%s\n" * | sort -t'_' -k1,1 -k2nr | awk -F'_' 'a[$1]++' | xargs rm
```

Results:

```
$ printf "%s\n" *
1k_03.txt
1l_04.txt
2a_06.txt
4c_04.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
$ ls
1k_02.txt  1l_02.txt  1l_04.txt  2a_06.txt  4c_04.txt
1k_03.txt  1l_03.txt  2a_05.txt  4c_03.txt
$ (typeset -A seen; for f (*_*(nOn)) let 'seen[${f%_*}]++' && rm -- $f)
$ ls
1k_03.txt  1l_04.txt  2a_06.txt  4c_04.txt
```

(see [How to use associative arrays safely inside arithmetic expressions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/627474) for why we're using `let` instead of `((...))` here).